# Pip installing 32 bit package instead of 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, pip

I ran into this issue while trying to install the regex package. pip seems to be installing the 32 bit wheel instead of the 64 bit one.

This is weird, especially since I only have 64-bit python. I'm running python 3.9.5, pip 21.1.2 on windows 10

Comment: What is the package

Comment: @Sujay Initially faced the issue with the regex package, but it occurs with other packages as well, so its an issue with pip, not the package

Comment: Did you try modifying python installation?

Comment: @Sujay Modifying it how? I've tried a uninstalling and reinstalling it again

Comment: @JohnHennig What details do you want me to provide?

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: @phd Gives me 64

Comment: `python --version`? `pip --version`?

Comment: @phd 3.9.5 and 21.1.2

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of anything that would cause it to do this. I cannot reproduce it on my other system either. Its just the one system that doesnt work

Comment: `pip --version` provides more than just version, it also prints its python version and the path to `site-packages`. I'm trying to find out if `pip` runs under a different 32-bit python.

Comment: @phd its running under 64-bit, 3.9. I only have one version of python installed anyway. (pip 21.1.2 from c:\users\sanath\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9))